# Understand rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I'm newbie in Rails ,So is there any document which help me to understand the internal process of commands. Like when I use 
    **$ rails server** , so I need to understand what the process going behind the scene and how its started webric server and create a deameon IP if I used option **$ rails server -d 198.0.0.0** etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can watch through all of **these screencasts** and documentation from **Rails Guide**.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

http://www.bigbinary.com/videos/2-how-rails-boots

http://railscasts.com/episodes/299-rails-initialization-walkthrough

Comment: Thanks for your response... and bigbinary blocked in my country.

Answer (score 2):

Railties is what takes care of the command line interface, including `rails server`.

This file should be your entrypoint: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb

You can see the default options and the option parser implemented in there.

However, if you want to dig deeper in how Rails communicates with the server, you should study [Rack](http://rack.github.com/), since Rails is after all a Rack app.

Comment: FYI - It seems the address to the server command file has changed to https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb